# How can we combine SavedStateHandler with LiveData Coroutine Builder?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, viewmodel-savedstate

In a typical Android ViewModel, we can easily create a Restorable LiveData using

```
val liveData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("SomeKey")
```

Whenever the liveData value is set, it is automatically saved and restorable

However, if we use the `liveData` coroutine builder (i.e. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata)

```
val liveDataSaved: LiveData<String> = liveData {
    emit(someValue)
}
```

How can we also join it with `savedStateHandle`? (e.g. when restoring, it will first retrieved the previous emitted value instead of reinitialize)

Note: I can do as below, just look hacky.

```
val liveDataSaved: LiveData<String> = liveData {
    val someValue = savedStateHandle.get("Key") ?: getValue()
    savedStateHandle.put("Key", someValue)
    emit(someValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) to combine multiple other live data sources and then observe on this resulting `MediatorLiveData` at the end.

In your case, you can have multiple sources to this `MediatorLiveData` something like below:

```
val liveDataValue = MediatorLiveData<String>().apply {
    var intermediateValue = ""

    fun update() {
        this.value = intermediateValue
    }

    addSource(savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("SomeKey")) {
        intermediateValue = it
        update()
    }

    addSource(
        liveData {
            emit(someValue)
        }
    ) {
        intermediateValue = it
        update()
    }
}
```